# Using angr/radare2 to estimate values given chunks of assembly

Tags: radare2, python, angr

I'm currently using radare2 in order to construct a simple CFG, each block/node in that graph is composed of one or more assembly instructions, I wish to estimate the value of specific register or stack position as best as I can.

Few examples:

**Example 1:**

```
xor rax, rax
inc rax
; Given these instructions, solve(rax) => 1
```

**Example 2:**

```
mov rcx, 3
mov rbx, rcx
mov rax, rbx
; Given the instructions above, solve(rax) => 3
```

**Example 3:**

```
mov rbx, rcx
mov rax, rbx
; Given the instructions above, solve(rax) => Unknown
```

**Example 4:**

```
mov rdx, 1
shl rdx, 2
add rdx, 3
mov [rsp], rdx
; Given the instructions above, solve([rsp]) => 7
```

I'm looking for a simple Python example to start with, which either takes opcodes directly or and address and evaluates/solve for specific register/stack position.

I've already looked into some symbolic execution examples, which looks like what I need, but I'm pretty new to this so a simple working example would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small angr script that can do so:

```
proj = angr.Project('...path...')
state = proj.factory.blank_state(addr=0x0804EA9E)
simulation = proj.factory.simgr(state)
ret = simulation.explore(find=0x0804EAA3)
print(ret.found[0].regs.ecx)
```

Between the addresses `0x0804EA9E` to `0x0804EAA3` I've got `mov ecx, 0Ah` so I get: `<BV32 0xa>` from the print.

I know its not much, but as I've said, I'm new. And hopefully this simple script will help others.

Really good resources to start with:

- https://docs.angr.io/core-concepts/states#state-presets
- https://blog.notso.pro/2019-03-20-angr-introduction-part0/